# How to use javascript data in Quart/Flask/Jinja2 template tag?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2, quart

I am using websockets within my Quart app in place of ajax. The aim is to be able to post a comment. A Quart websocket endpoint handles the backend side of things, and then I would like to append the comment to the page instantly from the data received from the websocket. This all working fine until I want to use either a template filter or utility context processor. I think some code will people to understand, so here is my websocket method in JavaScript/jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.comment_form').submit(function (e) {
      var add_comment_ws = $.simpleWebSocket({
        url: 'wss://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/websockets/_add_comment',
        timeout: 100,
        attempts: 10,
        dataType: 'json'
      });
      if (typeof $(this).data('post_id') !== 'undefined') {
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
      } else {
        var post_id = null;
      }
      if (typeof $(this).data('reply_id') !== 'undefined') {
        var reply_id = $(this).data('reply_id');
      } else {
        var reply_id = null;
      }
      var data = {
        comment_body: $(this).find('textarea').val(),
        post_id: post_id,
        reply_id: reply_id,
        user_id: $(this).data('user_id'),
        complete: false
      };
      console.log('[+] Sending data to websocket: <add_comment_ws>: content: ' +
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          console.log(key + ' - ' + value);
        })
      );
      add_comment_ws.send(data);
      $(this).find('textarea').val('')

      add_comment_ws.listen(function(data) {
        console.log('[+] Received data from websocket: <add_comment_ws>: content: ' +
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key + ' - ' + value);
          })
        );
        var comments_list = $('#comments_list_for_' + data.id);
        var comment_html = '<div class="comment">' +
                            '<p>' + data.comment_body +
                            '<p>' + data.user_display_name +
                            '<hr>' +
                            '</div>';
                            '<div class="comment">' +
                            ' <hr>' +
                            '  <div class="comment-grid-conatiner">' +
                            '    <div class="comment-grid-item-1">' +
                            '      <div class="comment-option-buttons comment-option-buttons-grid-conatiner">' +
                            '        <button class="comment-vote-up-button vote-button pseudo comment-option-buttons-grid-item-1" title="This comment is useful." aria-label="up vote" data-comment_id="' + data.comment_id + '" data-user_id="' + data.user_id + '"><i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>' +

                            '        <div class="vote-count comment-option-buttons-grid-item-2 comment-vote-count-' + data.comment_id + '" itemprop="upvoteCount" data-value="' + data.comment_score + '">' + data.comment_score + '</div>' +

                            '        <button class="vote-button pseudo comment-option-buttons-grid-item-3" title="This comment needs to be flagged." aria-label="up vote"><i class="fal fa-flag"></i></button>' +
                            '      </div>' +
                            '    </div>' +
                            '    <div class="comment-grid-item-2">' +
                            '      <p class="comment-body">' + data.comment_body + '</p>' +
                            '    </div>' +
                            '    <div class="comment-grid-item-3">' +
                            '      <span class="comment-display-name comment-grid-item-2">' +
                            '        <a class="comment-display-name-link" href="/users/user/' + data.user_id + '">' +
                                      data.user_display_name +
                            '        </a>' +
                            '      </span>' +
                            '      <span class="comment-date">' +
//This is where the problem is  --->> {{ human_date(data.created_at) }} + //<<--- 
                            '      </span>' +
                            '    </div>' +
                            '  </div>' +
                            '  <hr>';
        comments_list.append(comment_html);

      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have marked where the problem is in the code (it's at close to the bottom).

I receive an exception:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined
```

Which is expected at this point because within the jinja tag itthinks we are using python variables.

Is there a way to be able to do this?

Comment: Let jinja2 render the comment template on the server, then send back the final HTML via the websocket.

Comment: I want to do it without refreshing/reloading the page

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood you, could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: 1. have the server-side code that receives the comment object [call jinja2's rendering engine](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.render_template) using a comment template and the comment data 2. send the resulting HTML  string back to the browser and insert it. This way you're also getting rid of the ugly client-side HTML composition code.

Comment: ok I will try that out, it sounds good. If it works I will let you post as an aswer if you like and ill accept

Comment: @ChrisG, that has worked perfectly, if you want to put in an answer I will accelt so you get a few rep, if not I will be happy to answer my own question.

Comment: Feel free to add your answer, but this Q is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Ok, I don't know how you could possibly think that my question is the same as the one you suggested. My question was actually how to use javascript data objects inside a jinja2 template, I know the difference between server-side and client-side and I wasn't asking what the difference is, I only went with your suggested method because I don't have time to be waiting, I just needed a way to get it to work for now. I am getting pretty fed up with the whole "duplicate" thing on SO, my question and the suggested dupe are not even in the same context and the only relation is javascript!

Comment: I said it's *essentially* a duplicate, it's obviously not an exact duplicate. However, you *were* trying to use server-side template syntax / variables on the client-side. Since you didn't know how to resolve this, linking you to a question that explains the basic mechanism at length is the obvious thing to do. You'll also note that I didn't in fact mark your question as dupe. And `I don't have time to be waiting, I just needed a way to get it to work for now.` is precisely *not* how this website works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I rectified this by using [Chris G's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) suggestion in the comments. I ended up moving the HTML into a template and using the websocket endpoint to render the data in the HTML and return the HTML as the to the JavaScript.